# Evaluate the following log series

Tags: number-theory, analysis

log(2/3)+log(3/4)+log(4/5)+...
For this infinite series, what could be the value and how can it be evaluated. I guess it could diverge to negative infinity, but I was told that this series converges to a finite value. Please help

Comment: Who told you this series converges? Your original assumption was right - by the comparison test the series diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial sum is:
$$S_n=\ln{\left(\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac34\cdot\frac45\cdots \frac{n}{n+1}\right)}=\ln{\frac{2}{n+1}}=\ln 2-\ln{(n+1)}.$$
Taking limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\log(a/b)$ equals $\log a - \log b$. Using this, we can rewrite the series as:
$$(\log 2 - \log 3) + (\log 3 - \log 4) + \cdots + (\log(n+1) - \log(n+2)).$$

Since $\log 2 - \log 3 < -0.1$, and each term is larger than the next one, then each term of the sum $(-0.1) + (-0.1) + (-0.1) + \cdots$ is larger than in the original sequence. This sum diverges, so does the original sum diverge as well?

Comment: each term is of the format (log n - log n+1)

Comment: @SehraSahu Thanks for correcting my mistake! Sorry if you felt confused by such a big mistake, but I think the idea of my earlier edit was around the same.